# Angular2 tour of heroes - What does the colon in onSelect(hero: Hero) mean?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am doing Angular2 tour of heroes project   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html
.

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)">{{hero.name}}</li>
```

Here i can alert the the current hero name and id using the following function

```
onSelect(hero) {
        alert(hero.id);
   }
```

But why in the official tutorial it is using

```
onSelect(hero: Hero){

    }
```

why **hero: Hero** ?

also what is the meaning of `onSelect(hero: Hero): void { }` .

what is the meaning of

```
selectedHero: Heroes;
      onSelect(hero: Heroes): void {
      this.selectedHero = hero;
    }
```

Please help .

Comment: when you using  (click)="onSelect(hero)" you send hero. the hero type is Hero. and when you using typscript you need to decleare the type of hero

Comment: This is Typescript syntax - look at the documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you type 'hero', it will assume it has the type 'any'. When you say hero: Hero, you delimit the type of the variable to a 'Hero', which means the function will only accept parameters of the type Hero or abstractions of it.

EDIT: for the void part, this is the return type of your function. Void means it will return nothing.

EDIT2:

```
selectedHero: Hero

OnSelect(hero: Hero): void{
    this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

so the 'selectedHero: Hero' part you define a variabel 'selectedHero' of the type 'Hero'.

The you define your function 'OnSelect', which accepts a parameter 'hero' of the type 'Hero'. 'hero' will be the name you use to access the parameter in the function 'OnSelect'.

The function returns void, which means it returns nothing, and just does what is stated in the function.

the part this.selectedHero = hero; is trickier. Above in your component you defined a Hero variable with the name 'hero'. It is outside of the function's scope. 'this' refers to the component class you are in, it's a keyword used to access it. So to access a variable which is outside of your function, but still in your object, you use the keyword 'this'.

Ok so when you click a hero, the OnSelect function gets triggered and you pass on the hero you just clicked ( the hero: 'Hero'). What you then do is set the hero of your current object ( this.selectedHero ) equals to the hero you just clicked ( hero: Hero ).

Every time you click on a hero, it will replace the selectedHero with the one you clicked.

PS: My explanation of the 'this' keyword is made as abstract possible to comprehend, I know there's a lot more to it then i explained, but this was for the sake of the person asking, as he is new to developing.

Comment: @Ram void is what the function returns. It means this function will return nothing, and only does the thing that is stated in this function.

Comment: could you please explain what is the meaning of        selectedHero: Hero;     onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
      this.selectedHero = hero;
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136830/discussion-between-tanguyb-and-ram).

Comment: In my understanding of the part "this.selectedHero = hero;", the current object ( this.selectedHero ) points to the hero that was just clicked ( hero: Hero ), not receives a copy of it. Am I right?

Answer (score 5):

Syntax is:

```
methodName(variable: Class): returnType {
    // your code here
}
```

**EDIT:** Check out the typescript documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html).

Comment: hi, from where you get this information ?. Please give link .

Comment: Check out the typescript documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 2):

In typescript , it indicates the type of Hero, which is of type object 'Hero'.

Where Hero is a class,

```
export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}


onSelect(hero: Hero){}
```

Comment: Please explain. I didn't understand . also what about that void ?

Comment: void it is a method type, which does not return anything

Comment: @Sajeetharan Hero isn't always an interface. I know it is a good practice for loose coupling it, but I think he is pretty new to developing and this will only give him a headache.

I think hero is a class in his example.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript provides some [built-in types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) out of the box like String, Number, Boolean, any and you can also create custom types.

Unlike JavaScript, you can have strong typing support with TypeScript that gives you compile time error checking.

Strong typing can ensure that you always pass the correct number of parameters as well as the correct type of parameters to a method.

You can create a custom type by using a [class](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) or an [interface](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

Let's create a custom interface type named Hero:

```
class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

You can now use this type to set a type on a method's parameter like this:

```
onSelect(hero: Hero): void {

}
```

If you pass any other value that is not of type `Hero` to this method, you will have compile time error.

`void` is an indication that this method does not return anything. You can return any object from this method and can also specify the same type by replacing the void keyword. Example:

```
onSelect(hero: Hero): boolean {
    return false;
}
```

Overall, typescript provides good strong typing support that can save you lots of time as the error is encountered while you write code instead of finding this issue at run-time like JavaScript.

Play with this [TypeScript playground here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) to learn more about TypeScript.

```
selectedHero: Heroes;
   onSelect(hero: Heroes): void {
   this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

You will often find usage of `selectedItem` in application like these which is a   class member to save the selected item so that you can use it to work with it say for displaying that item or edit that item.

In this example it is `selectedHero`. When user selects a hero, you assign that selected hero to your class member `selectedHero`. And then this `selectedHero` is used to highlight user selection in that Angular example.

Comment: Thank you friend .

Comment: @Ram I've updated my answer for your selectedHero query.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

`hero: Hero`

you delimit the type of the variable to a 'Hero', which means the function will only accept parameters of the type Hero or abstractions of it. So, we are using like that

Answer (score 0):

I thought that 'hero' variable is related somehow to variables defined at earlier stages of the tutorial (that were also called 'hero'). But finally understood that it's NOT.

So I'd recommend trying out:

```
selectedHero: Heroes;

      onSelect(whyyoucalleditheroandblurredthewholetutorial: Heroes): void {
      this.selectedHero = whyyoucalleditheroandblurredthewholetutorial;
    }
```